# Updating a table data using other table data

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables like

tbl_image:

```
Serial  |   Src            | Albumid  
________|__________________|________
   1    |   /root/wewe.jpg |   20
   2    |   /root/wewe.jpg |   21
   3    |   /root/wewe.jpg |   21
   4    |   /root/wewe.jpg |   23
   5    |   /root/wewe.jpg |   18
```

tbl_Album:

```
Albumid |  Albumname       | AlbumCover  
________|__________________|________
   20   |   AAA            |   null
   21   |   bbb            |   null
   31   |   vcc            |   null
   42   |   ddd            |   null
   18   |   eee            |   null
```

What i want to do is change the AlbumCover value in  tbl_Album by using SerialNo in first table..

Like

```
    Update tbl_Album set AlbumCover='something' where Albumid='tbl_Image.Serial'
```

I am not good in sql in complex queries...somebody help me plz!!!

Comment: Can foreign key helps me in this scene??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
Update tbl_Album AS album
set album.AlbumCover=image.Serial
FROM tbl_Album as album
JOIN tbl_image AS image
    ON image.Albumid = album.Albumid
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` both tables on `Albumid`. In the past i also found it  "difficult" to remember is where to place the `FROM`-clause (behind the `SET`):

```
UPDATE a SET a.AlbumCover = i.Serial
FROM  tbl_Album a INNER JOIN tbl_image i
    ON a.Albumid = i.Albumid
```